# how to write views for our own custom module?

Tags: 7, views

I am new to drupal. I have created one form submission module like this

```
 <?php
function form_test_permission()
{
return array(
'submit_form_test' =>array(
'title' =>('submit_form_test'),
'description' =>('submit the form_test form'),
),
);
}
function form_test_menu() {
$items=array();
$items['application']=array(
'title' =>'Application Form',
'type' =>MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
'access arguments' => array('submit_form_test'),
'page callback' =>'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('form_test_form'),
);
return $items;
}

function form_test_form($form,&$form_state){
$form['firstname'] =array(
'#title' =>t('Firstname'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
);
$form['lastname'] =array(
'#title' =>t('Lastname'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
);
$form['addr']=array(
'#title' =>t('Address'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
);
$form['age']=array(
'#title' =>t('Age'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
);
$form['submit']=array(
'#value' => 'submit',
'#type'=> 'submit',
);
return $form;
}
function form_test_form_submit($form,&$form_state) {
$ft_id=db_insert('form_test')
->fields(array(
'firstname' => $form_state['values']['firstname'],
'lastname' =>$form_state['values']['lastname'],
'addr'=>$form_state['values']['addr'],
'age'=>$form_state['values']['age']
))
->execute();
drupal_set_message(t('Saved.'));
}
```

if I go like localhost/drupal-example/application.. this module works.. But I want to display this module in front page.I referred a lot. But it doesn't works. Can anyone guide me how to write a view function in this module?

Comment: "display this module in front page" - what do you mean by that? You want to create block to put on frontpage? Or to set module's page as front page? Or what exactly?

Comment: But I wrote this as page..I want to this as page in views..not as block in views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to use a custom module's table with Views, you need to use [hook_views_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7)().

Even better, I would recommend that you invest some time to learn about [entities](http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/creating-own-entities-entity-api). Entities are much better for most and thay can be almost immediately used in views.

To define a custom view into your module, put it in file `module.views_default.inc` (replacing with your module name), in a function [module_views_default_views](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_default_views/7)().

Comment: can u give example format codes for my module

Comment: I would be glad to, but I do not know your tables and specifics. One more page that could help you with that is https://drupal.org/comment/5687844#comment-5687844

Comment: Afterwards, to add a view in module_views_default_views(), simply create it in Views UI and use the export feature to get the code.